# Vertices/edges between specified nodes

Tags: r, igraph

This seems like an easy problem to solve, but even after a week, I can't find a solution to this.

I have an undirected graph with 1700+ nodes and 5000+ edges. I would like to filter/subset this graph for a source node and other target nodes, regardless of the order of the neighborhood. I tried the following code and it works for this example dataset, but `all_simple_paths` doesn't terminate for my real data set.

In this working example, I am showing the connections between A and C & F.

```
library(igraph)
gg <- graph.data.frame(data.frame(n1 = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'F', 'E'), 
                              n2 = c('D', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'F', 'C', 'F')),
                   directed = FALSE,
                   vertices = LETTERS[1:6])
plot(gg, layout = layout_with_kk(gg))
paths <- all_simple_paths(gg, from = "A", to = c("C", "F"))
gg_s <- subgraph(gg, v = unique(rapply(paths, f = c)))
plot(gg_s, layout = layout_with_kk(gg_s))
```

I also tried `subcomponent` and `intersection`, but `subcomponent` returns all possible connections. I tried creating ego graphs and then doing an intersection, but that's not giving the best results.

Comment: What exactly is the desired output for this sample input?

Comment: The output should show the connection between A & C and A & F. The above code does show that, but it doesn't work for large graphs. I will edit the post to make that clear.